# How to fight in a civil war in Elite Dangerous?

Tags: elite-dangerous

I'm looking to fight against Diamond Frogs in Ngaledi in order for a Federal government takeover (mainly for the experience). I've been fighting in conflict zones, but I want to delve into Checkpoints to help the controlling faction fall. If doing this, would I get a bounty? Also, if I did, would the Federal faction be angry at me, and attack? Or would nobody during a civil war, and being wanted is OK?

Answer (score 5):

During an active War or Civil War, the only actions that change influence for either faction involved is collecting combat bonds from kills in conflict zones.

If you fire at a ship without a red “Lawless” or “Wanted” in the target info area, you will become wanted by the faction controlling that space. If you attack a ship, you lose reputation with the faction whose ship you attacked (eventually becoming “Hostile”).

It’s not clear what you plan to do in the Checkpoints, but those are the basics of how influence, reputation and crimes work during War or Civil War.